# Changing size for eye icon in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I'm dealing with strange CSS styles in angular material:

[image]

as you can see here that the eye icon ripple is going out from the input and I'm trying to fix it, so any idea how to?

PS: I have tried the following:

```
mat-form-field
  > .mat-form-field-wrapper
  > .mat-form-field-flex
  > .mat-form-field-outline {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

and I have the following code:

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
    <input
      matInput
      [type]="hide ? 'text' : type"
    />
```

but none is worked, so basically I want to decrease the size of the shadow when I click on the eye icon, but no luck, any assistance?

Answer (score 0):

I used scale() function to change size of icons in html like below and here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aapwe3?file=src%2Fapp%2F.%2Finput-clearable-example.html)

```
<mat-form-field class="example-form-field">
  <mat-label>Clearable input</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="value">
  <button mat-button *ngIf="value" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="value=''">
    <mat-icon class="transformation">close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

and css:

```
.transformation {
  transform: scale(50%); // 50% for half its size
}
```

Comment: Any stackblitz link will be more helpful to check real-time :-)

Comment: I updated my answer with a stackblitz link.